# Build Eclipse Makefile project from command line

Tags: c++, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have created Eclipse Makefile c++ project with intention to build project also without Eclipse. But I got error while run make in terminal:

```
Makefile:15: *** Build mode  not supported by this Makefile.  Stop.
```

How to fix that? Why I should need Eclipse Makefile if I can't build it with make?

Makefile content:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))

OBJS = boiler.o

ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),debug)
    CFLAGS += -g
else ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),profile)
    CFLAGS += -O2
else ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),run)
    CFLAGS += -O2
else ifeq ($(BUILD_MODE),linuxtools)
    CFLAGS += -g -pg -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
    LDFLAGS += -pg -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
else
    $(error Build mode $(BUILD_MODE) not supported by this Makefile)
endif

all:    boiler

boiler: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o:    $(PROJECT_ROOT)%.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

%.o:    $(PROJECT_ROOT)%.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -fr boiler $(OBJS)
```

Comment: `make BUILD_MODE=linuxtools` ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly how you created your Makefile ...

... but the problem is clearly that your Makefile happens to rely on the variable "$(BUILD_MODE)" ...

... and, the way you're running "make", BUILD_MODE isn't being set to one of your options, or isn't being set at all.

SUGGESTION: Type this on the command line:  `make BUILD_MODE=debug`

PS:

- Equivalently, you could define BUILD_MODE as an environment variable, e.g. `set BUILD_MODE=debug` (DOS prompt) or `export BUILD_MODE-debug` (Linux term)
- "BUILD_MODE" isn't "required".  It's just a convention.  That your "Makefile generator" happened to add when it created your particular makefile.

Comment: @vico: Is everything working for you now?  Did you resolve the problem?

Comment: FWIW, `BUILD_MODE=debug make` will also work. It has the effect of setting the BUILD_MODE environment variable, exporting it to the make executable, and then deleting it before the next command is run.